# Reading variable-sized structs into a common buffer and parsing the bytes accordingly

Tags: c, linux, sockets, struct

I am writing an app that uses `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` socket Linux APIs though the challenge is the data being sent and received are not of the same size so one struct could be passed of size 10 bytes while the other could be at least 20 bytes.

The struct contains a `header` member that identifies the type of struct which could be parsed first but you specify the number of bytes you want to read in `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` calls...which you don't know in advanced until you read the `header` byte

- how could you read the `header` byte without knowing the sizeof(bytes) to read at compile time to know how to parse the struct? Because once you know what `header` is, `read()` has already been executed. If you read 100 bytes and none of the structs are that big but what if you end up receiving 20 bytes instead of 30?
- how could you deserialize the struct on the receiver end into a  common data structure? Does the idea of using `uint8_t buffer[]` which stores the struct info byte-by-byte sound practical? Perhaps I would have to do bit manipulation to make sure you are parsing the desired number of bytes to represent data? The following seems to work but probably still doesn't cover different other corner cases and more importantly, is it SAFE to read the `header` byte into `deserializedData` as I did?

```c
typedef struct {
   int header, a, b;
} Pkt;

void client()
{
   struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

   memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
 
  int socketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7799);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

  // connect the socket to the server 
  if (connect(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
  {
    printf ("connect error\n");
  }

  Pkt pkt = {.header = 0xA, .a = 5, .b = 10};
  Pkt secondPkt = {.header = 0xB, .a = 15, .b = 100};
  
  int bytesSent = sendto(socketFd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0, NULL, 0);
}

void server()
{
    uint8_t deserializedData[100] = {0};

    int socketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7799);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

    // bind the struct to the socket
    if (bind(socketFd, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    {
      printf ("bind failed!\n");
    }

    int clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr); 

    while(1)
    {
      recvfrom(socketFd, deserializedData, 100, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
      int header = deserializedData[0];
      // execute a corresponding state machine based on header 
      switch(header) {
        case struct_A: 
          // ...
        case struct_B:
         // ...
      }

    }
     
}
```

Comment: You're essentially asking how to serialize and deserizalize structs as byte streams. _Strongly_ consider using an existing serialization library to build and interpret the streaming binary form instead of rolling your own. An example is https://google.github.io/flatbuffers, but there are many others.

Comment: I'm not sure if I could use something like flatbutter library into this project. Do you think it's not safe to store `header` into `deserializedData` like I did?

Comment: You can do absolutely nothing whatsoever correctly if you ignore the return value of `recvfrom` and `sendto` (and all other functions).

Comment: right. On this note, how would you go about verifying that ALL the bytes have been received before getting out of `read()` given you wouldn't know the size until you read the `header` byte as described?

Comment: @Jazzy Unlike stream sockets, with datagram sockets you get always get the whole message.  As long as your buffer can hold the maximum message size and you use the return value of `recvfrom` to get the message size you should be fine.

Comment: so there's no way a portion of a message would get received and rather a full message or nothing...and in either case, one would have to invoke `recvfrom()` again?